# Compile error: base operand of ‘->’ has non-pointer type ‘Token’

Tags: c++

I get the error mentioned in the title when trying to compile my c++ code.  I'm having trouble understanding what I did wrong here.

The compiler has a problem with my implementation of the `bool operator==(Token )` function.  I thought this was the way to overload an operator.

Any clues as to why the compiler doesn't like me referring to 
`this->terminal` or `this->lexeme`?

```
class Token {
    public:
        tokenType terminal;
        std::string lexeme;
        Token *next;

        Token();
        bool operator==(Token &t);
    private:
        int lexemelength, line, column;
};

bool Token::operator==(Token &t) {
    return ((this->terminal == t->terminal) &&
            (this->lexeme == t->lexeme));
}
```

Comment: It's not so much the `this` as it is the `t`.

Comment: Note that the canonical declaration of the comparison operator would be `bool operator==(const Token &t) const;` (where I added two extra `const` indications).

Comment: @qream If this answered your question, feel free to accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 12):

Take a close look at your types. `t` is a [reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) (`Token &t`) meaning it must be referred to using the dot operator (`.`).

References are not pointers; think of them as already dereferenced pointers without putting the actual object on the stack (passing "by reference").

Comment: Thanks Qix for the answer.  I stared at it for a while and figured out what I was doing wrong.

Comment: That's what we're here for!

Comment: I'd like to add that if you have a pointer to a pointer as a reference, you still refer to it with a `->` (i.e. if you had `void** p;` and then `someFunc(void*& p)`, you'd still refer to it with a `->`, but treat it as if it were a `void*`.